# Horror novel from the 1990s involving vampires, the cult of Kali, and thuggees

Tags: story-identification, novel, horror, vampire

I purchased this book second-hand in the late 90's, so it was probably published somewhere between 1989-1998. I'm basing this on the fact that the book was near new condition when I bought it. The book was definitely classified as 'horror'.

The story is set in Victorian London. It features some fairly grisly murders. There are occult elements. There are suspected (or maybe actual) murders by vampires. The narrative also features a connection to the British Raj - the protagonist may have served in colonial India. The cult of Kali is a huge factor in the story. Kali may be an actual character, but I'm not 100% certain about that.  There are thuggees adding to the body count, with ritual killings.

- The narrative is not epigrammatic, but told in third person omniscient narration.
- It is a novel of 300+ pages.
- The writing is very descriptive, lush, and poetic - in a similar fashion to Tanith Lee's decadent style.
- The book was a paperback and  had a shiny black cover - I have no memory of the cover illustration.

The book is definitely not *No Blood Spilled* by Les Daniels, and it isn't *Supping With Panthers* by Tom Holland.

Comment: This sounds like an Anne Rice novel to me but I'm not familiar enough with her work to know which one.

Comment: Thanks Matt - unfortunately it is not an Anne Rice novel. I've read many of her books and  I did a 'plot-check' of the ones I haven't read just to make sure...and regrettably Anne Rice has not written the novel that I'm chasing.